# Run an interactive shell from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, script

I'm currently writing a Bash script that creates an SSH tunnel. Once this is done, I would like the script to open a new local (!) interactive shell so that I can work on my system with the SSH tunnel open.

Once I type `exit` the local shell should be closed, and the original script continues to run.

My current approach basically looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

ssh -N user@ip -L xxx:xxx &
SSH_CONNECTION=${!}

trap "kill ${SSH_CONNECTION}" ERR

sleep 3
bash -i

kill ${SSH_CONNECTION}
```

So far, everything works - except running the local shell. I actually get a shell, and I can even type in it, but nothing happens when I hit `<Return>`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you found such strange `trap`'s signal `ERR` ? AFAIK it doesn't exist. (Proof: `/bin/kill -L`)

Comment: Ohh, it is `bash`ism, sorry, missed that, ignore previous then

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-f` so the connection will go to background once it will be established. Then you will not need the `&`:

```
ssh -Nf  -L xxx:xxx user@ip
```

and the processing should get into your `bash`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I wanted to run a **local** shell, not a **remote** one. So, unfortunately, this does not work :-/

Comment: did you read and  try that?